# How to show hidden part of an image which is inside a fixed height div, using just the CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a container div of size 150x150 which contains an image of size 150x180. The div has `overflow: hidden` css property enabled so a part of the image is hidden. Div size is fixed 150x150, image height may vary from image to image though. When I hover on the div or image, I want to vertically move the image so that the hidden part of the image could be shown to the viewer.

To make this functionality work I've used jQuery. Here's what I'm doing (my css, html, jQuery code blocks):

```js
$("#container").mouseenter(function() {
    img_height = $(this).find('img').height();
    $(this).find('img').animate({
        'top': 150 - img_height
    }, 300);
});

$("#container").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find('img').animate({
        'top': 0
    }, 300);
});
```

```css
#container {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid;
    position: relative;
}
#container img { 
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <img class="fl" src="http://media.dcentertainment.com/sites/default/files/superman-150x180.jpg" width="150"/>
</div>
```

Is it possible to achieve the same functionality by using css transitions? If the answer is yes, then how?

Comment: not sure why am I down voted. I thought it's a good legitimate question

Comment: [This question is being discussed on Meta.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285209/1157100)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. The main idea is setting initial vertical offset in style when image will be loaded.

```
<img onload="this.style.bottom = '' + (150 - this.offsetHeight) + 'px' src="..." />
```

But it is not entirely pure HTML/CSS solution.

```css
.container {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container img {
    position: absolute;
    transition: bottom 0.3s;
}

.container img:hover {
    bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://media.dcentertainment.com/sites/default/files/superman-150x180.jpg" onload="this.style.bottom = '' + (150 - this.offsetHeight) + 'px'" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

height 100% should do the trick!

```css
#container {
    width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 overflow: hidden;
 border: 1px solid;
 position: relative;
}
#container img:hover { 
    height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
 <img class="fl" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQiWGXo4U6CCvNItlDYFgEQz4d3T-YjLj13nqUZ-crpAr3qMPx-"/>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your comment @Alain1405, but it's not as simple as that. I want the image proportions to be constant, so if the image width:height is 4:3, it should remain as it is, and the hidden portion of image should be shown to the viewer by moving the image in entirety not by contracting the image.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use transition on image.
2. Use fixed px height for the div that contains image.
3. No use to absolute position the image(only required if there are other elements inside the `div`

Here is the code

```
<div class="imgWrap">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/150/180" alt="" class="img1"> 
</div>
```

and here is css code

```
.imgWrap{
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.img1{

  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.imgWrap:hover .img1{
  margin-top:-30px
}
```

I have created a pen for this
http://codepen.io/Prashantsani/pen/BywmoN

Comment: the approach you've suggested works for all images of a fixed height (150px for example). But for images of different heights the above code will still set -30px margin. How to set the variable margin?